# Regex Python Error

Tags: python, regex

I'm tring to find `<20>  UNIQUE      Registered` in `hostname   <20>  UNIQUE      Registered` and replace it with `""` in python. Below is my code. Please inform me where my syntax is wrong to replace this string:

```
string = string.replace(r'<\d*2>  UNIQUE      Registered ', "")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace()` cannot do regular expression substitution. Use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "hostname <20>  UNIQUE      Registered"
>>> re.sub(r"<\d{2}>\s+UNIQUE\s+Registered", "", s)
'hostname '
```

where `\d{2}` would match 2 subsequent digits, `\s+` - one or more space characters.

As a side note, could not you just split the string by space and get the first item:

```
>>> s.split()[0]
'hostname'
```

Comment: The `split` method worked. I couldn't seem to get the `sub` method to work